# How to remove the extra white color space between table cells?

Tags: html

As on the image yellow colored area is an image.

Pink color area is also separate PNG file which doesn't have white color borders.

But when I place those two images on HTML table I can see there is a small gap between two cells.

Is there any way to remove this gap by filling the image on the entire cell?

This is how my cell formatting looks like.

```
<table  align="center">
  <tr >
    <td><img src="img/scriptlayers/27368576_860818550757435_5141546751659517385_o_0000_Layer-2.png"/></td>
    <td><img src="img/scriptlayers/27368576_860818550757435_5141546751659517385_o_0001_Layer-3.png"/></td>
    <td><img src="img/scriptlayers/27368576_860818550757435_5141546751659517385_o_0002_Layer-1.png"/></td>

img {
    max-width: 100%;
    display:block;
}
```

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this

```
<table align="center" border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0">
```